# Как установить css свойство для состояния :hover на JS/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Как скриптом установить CSS свойство для состояния `hover` элемента?

Сделать, например:

```
#home_button:hover {opacity: 0.3;}
```

, если свойство для `hover` не было установлено или было установлено другое.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решить Вашу задачу можно следующим образом:

```js
    var elem = document.getElementById('opacity');
    elem.onmouseover = function () {
        elem.style.opacity = "0.4";
    };
    elem.onmouseleave = function () {
        elem.style.opacity = "1";
    }
```

```css
    .div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #003eff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="div" id="opacity">Пурум Пум Пум</div>
```

Это будет работать даже, если был установлен параметр `hover` в CSS у данного элемента.

Comment: То же самое на Jquery.

`var elem = document.getElementById('opacity');
elem.mouseover(function(){
 elem.css("opacity", 0.6);
})
elem.mouseleave(function () {
 elem.css("opacity", 1);
})`

еще не разобрался с этим вашим форматированием. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если чистый JS то это [сюда смотреть](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave) Если с использованием библиотеки jQuery то [метод hover](https://basicweb.ru/jquery/jquery_event_hover.php)